# Creating Dynamic Sheet Cell Reference List for pulling numbers to SUM

Tags: google-sheets, cell, google-sheets-formula, cell-array, excel-indirect

I've been working on building a data analysis sheet, which is quite verbose at the moment and a bit more complicated than it should be as I've been trying to figure this out. Please note, I work doing student data in a school.

Basically, I have two sets of input data:

1. Data imported from a CSV file that includes test data and codes for Common Core Standards and the questions tied to those standards as a whole class summary
2. Data imported from a CSV file that includes individual scores by question

I am looking to construct 2 views:

1. A view that collates and displays data of individual standards per student that includes a dropdown to change the standard allowing a teacher to see class performance by standard in a broad view. The drop-down is populated dynamically from the input data (so staff could eventually dump data and go directly to reports)
2. A view that collates and displays data of individual students broken down by performance on each standard allowing a teachers to see the broader spectrum for each student. The student drop-down is populated from Source list 2.

I have been able to build the first view, but am struggling with the second. I've been able to separate the question codes and develop strings of cell references to the scoring data, including a dynamic reference to the row the selected student's score data appears on in the second source set from above.

I tried to pass through an indirect() formula into a sum() so as to process for a mean evaluation, and have encountered errors. I think SUM() doesn't process comma-separated cell reference lists from Indirect() [or in general] or there is something that I am missing to help parse it. Here is the formula I have tried:

```
=Sum(vlookup(D7,CCCodeManip!$A:$C,3,false))
```

CCCodeManip!C:C includes the created text (based on the dynamic standards and question codes, etc), here's an example of what would be found there:

```
'M-ADI'!M17, 'M-ADI'!N17, 'M-ADI'!O17, 'M-ADI'!P17, 'M-ADI'!Q17, 'M-ADI'!R17, 'M-ADI'!J17
```

I need these to be dynamic so that teachers can input different sets of standards, question, and student data and the sheet automatically collates and reports it in uniform ways (with an upward bound of 20 standards as I currently have it built)

Here is a link to the sheet I built, with names and ID anonymized. There's a CRAP TON of sub-tabs, and that's really just being able to split apart and re-combine data neatly without things error-ing out due to data overlapping, aside from a few different attempts and different approaches to parse the cell reference strings.

The first two tabs are the current status of the data views. I plan to hide a bunch of the functional stuff that is there to help pull data accurately.

The 3rd and 4th tab are the source data sets. 5th is a modified version of source data that allows me to reference things better, and I've tried to arrange the sheets most relevant towards the front of the set.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fR_2n60lenxkvjZSzp2VDGyTUO6l-3wzwaV4P-IQ_5Y/edit?usp=sharing

Some have a different approach? I am aware that I might be as far as I cn go with this and perhaps should consider scripts - my coding experience is a bit out of date and my strength is more with the formulas, but I can dig into things with some direction, if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I noticed something.

It seems the failure is in the indirect reference:

```
    =indirect(CCCodeManip!C3)
```

The string I am trying to parse via indirect is going to be generated into something like this, dynamic from reference to other data:

```
    'M-ADI'!M17, 'M-ADI'!N17, 'M-ADI'!O17, 'M-ADI'!P17, 'M-ADI'!Q17, 'M-ADI'!R17, 'M-ADI'!J17
```

The indirect returns the error that the above string is *not* a cell reference with the #REF code.

Can someone give me a clue as to what is causing this? I am going to dig into the docs on Indirect() from google and will post anything that I find.

*Perhaps it is that indirect() can't handle lists, but only specific references and arrays, which may require me a to build a sheet to do the SUM formula on for each question set (?)*

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out, but i Ended up parsing the data differently, basically doing the sum based on individual cell references and a separate sum formula, bypassing the need to do it all at once, it jsut makes my sheets a lot dirtier! I am eventually going to see if code could do it better if I need to, but this is closed for now.

Basically, I did individual cell references to recall scores in a row, then used a separate SUM formula, and created references / structures to be able to pull those sum() results. Achieves the same end, but with extra crap on the sheet.